# Could not find org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0 after removing jcenter() in Android

Tags: android, gradle, capacitor, jcenter

My project is in Ionic 5 and just upgraded to Capacitor 3. After this upgrade I am am getting the following error.

```
Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
```

So, as per the suggested solutions from different forums I first added `mavenCentral()` on top of `center()` in `build.gradle` and build the project. This was successful. Then I removed the `jcenter()`. After this build I am getting the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/**/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/**/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework.jar
       - file:/Users/**/android/app/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/**/android/app/libs/framework.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > project :capacitor-android
         project :app > project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
```

Is there a way I can add the missing depedency and remove `jcenter()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cordova-android 10 is now published on maven, so it's possible to remove jcenter entries from you Capacitor project.

First replace both `jcenter()` entries with `mavenCentral()` in `projectName/android/build.gradle` file.

Then increase `minSdkVersion` value to `22` and `cordovaAndroidVersion` version to `'10.1.1'` in `projectName/android/variables.gradle` file.

Finally sync gradle and you should be able to run your app.

OLD ANSWER:

cordova is only distributed in jcenter at the moment, so you can't remove the `jcenter()` entry from your `build.gradle`

The

> Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.

should be just a warning for now, not an error.

Comment: Sorry, It's a warning, not an error. I am not using any Cordova plugin but not sure why `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins` is still in the project. Could you please tell me if I can remove it or it states with Capacitor 3?

Comment: cordova dependency is needed for capacitor to compile because it has code for the cordova plugin compatibility

Comment: Thank you!! I am going to keep jcenter as there is no point keeping both mavenCentral and jcenter.

Comment: If you remove jcenter which it now appears to be gone.   You need to change your cordovaAndroidVersion from 7.0.0 to  10.0.0

Comment: yeah, if you check my answer again, I already mentioned that, but used 10.1.1 instead of 10.0.0

Comment: Thank you @jcesarmobile your answer help me solve the above issue but after i solved this one the Following Error appeared i don't know how i solve it i have try different ways. Can you give any insight in this one ? i would really appreciate your help 
''' 
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

'''

Comment: I think I’ve seen that error when using Java jdk 16, using an older jdk should fix the problem.