# Github Actions: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Tags: android, github-actions, cicd, ionic5

I have the following errors since 2 days whereas no change has done on configuration of CI/CD of Github Actions.

Anyone can help me please ?

The following behavior is strange:
Gradle 7.0.2 seems to be used but the error talk about Gradle 8.0.

```
Run cd android && ./gradlew assembleDefaultDebug Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip ..............10%...............20%...............30%..............40%...............50%...............60%...............70%..............80%...............90%...............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.0.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app WARNING:: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.

> Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins WARNING:: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats. Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> ...
> Task :capacitor-rate-app:packageDebugResources

> Task :app:checkDefaultDebugAarMetadata FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDefaultDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:DefaultDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/runner/work/rework/rework/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/runner/work/rework/rework/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework.jar
       - file:/Users/runner/work/rework/rework/android/app/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/runner/work/rework/rework/android/app/libs/framework.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :capacitor-android
         project :app > project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 51s Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings 48 actionable tasks: 48 executed Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: When you upgrade to gradle 8.0 you can use the assistant anyway and it will point you the solutions or which things are not compatible exactly, wouldn't spend time on this if it doesn't give any problems

Answer (score 0):

About the cordova library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306119/could-not-find-org-apache-cordovaframework7-0-0-after-removing-jcenter-in-an/68306206#68306206):

> cordova-android 10 is now published on maven, so it's possible to
> remove jcenter entries from you Capacitor project.
>
> First replace both `jcenter()` entries with `mavenCentral()` in
> `projectName/android/build.gradle` file.
>
> Then increase `minSdkVersion` value to `22` and `cordovaAndroidVersion`
> version to `'10.1.1'` in `projectName/android/variables.gradle` file.
>
> Finally sync gradle and you should be able to run your app.

If you don't want or can't increase `minSdkVersion` you can try use older versions by either:

- Finding the compiled library (or compiling it yourself) and including it in your project, or
- Adding the library files in your project directly.

You can find the project [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/7.0.x).

Comment: I can't upgrade cordova to 10.1.1 for now because to much dependency to upgrade. There is no solution without upgrading cordova ?

Comment: @clem i talk about that in the end of the answer, see the edit. You'll need to download the project or find it compiled somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is about JFrog and impact all project using Cordova < 10.

Discussion is avialable here https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/6672